# Using colliderect in Pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

How do I tell python to detect whether two objects/ images touch each other? For example when an image of pacman touches an image of a ghost?

Comment: You might like to provide an example code snippet so it makes it easier to answer your question

Answer (score 2):

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect

> colliderect()
>
> test if two rectangles overlap
>
> colliderect(Rect) -> bool
>
> Returns true if any portion of either rectangle overlap (except the
>   top+bottom or left+right edges).

If the only collision detection between sprites is between pac-man and other objects, then just call `colliderect` on every combination of pacman's collision rectangle and every other collision rectangle.

If every single combination of collisions can be meaningful, then produce a big list of all of them and `colliderect` each rectangle with each rectangle further along in the list.

Every collision that occurs, you can choose to do something - you could even call both objects, passing the other object that collided, and thereby allowing the logic to be contained within one or both of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using `Sprite`s for your pacman and ghost? If so you want one of the sprite collision functions: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide

Otherwise, use the `Rect` collision Patashu links.